Opposite sides on the different platforms
In my React Native app, I have the following style for my container:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 25,
    right: 30,
  },
});

On Android, the container is on the top Left side, but on iPhone, it is on the top right side.
It also happens then I use a flexbox:
anotherContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    paddingVertical: 18
},

The sides are opposite between the platforms.
Why it happens?
How can I set the same side for both?
